# Transfer from one cPanel to another cPanel without WHM access

Tags: cpanel, transfer

I have `cPanel` access on two different servers and would like to transfer from one server to another. The original size of the account on the first server is close to 15GB.

Currently, the only two ways I can think of are:

1. Backup using `cPanel` then Restore on the second server. But this process times out. I get "Failed - Network error" error
2. Use FTP App like Filezilla to login and transfer files from that. I haven't tested this but I think it first downloads the files on my local machine (temp folder) then uploads them to the second server.

My problem with option 2 is that this means I will end up using 30GB of data transfer if it actually does that.

What is the best way to transfer from server to server using `cPanel`?

Answer (score 0):

I have limited knowledge on this. I will suggest you some tips.

1.Backup using cPanel then Restore on the second server. But this process times out. I get "Failed - Network error" error

> > The backup creation is failed due to the high size of account. So that reason that way is not possible.

2. Use FTP App like Filezilla to login and transfer files from that. I haven't tested this but I think it first downloads the files on my local machine (temp folder) then uploads them to the second server.

> > You can download the whole content to your PC or download one folder by folder like first home, mail, and etc and upload to new cpanel account using ftp

Could you please open a support ticket to your hosting provider they will help you create from server backend using /script/pkgacct.

Thank you.

Comment: Sorry but how would I use this /script/pkgacct ? I abandoned the process last year and find myself at the same place again this year :-(